# CodeDeploy Deployment failed to stop Application

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

**The overall deployment failed because too many individual instances failed deployment, too few healthy instances are available for deployment, or some instances in your deployment group are experiencing problems.**

*Above Error is on AWS Code Deploy By using Ec2 instance, Deployment is going to fail.*

I have tried with Code Deploy Agent method, then also i am getting same Error, Is there any other option to resolve this issue, please let me know anyone knonw's the answer.

In Events Option, it was showing like this

```
Event             Duration    Status   Errorcode    Start time                  End time
ApplicationStop   0 seconds   Failed                Aug 12, 2021 11:07 AM    Aug 12, 2021 11:07 AM 
                                                         (UTC+5:30)                  (UTC+5:30)
DownloadBundle                Skipped
BeforeInstall                 Skipped
Install                       Skipped
AfterInstall                  Skipped
ApplicationStart              Skipped
ValidateService               Skipped.
```

Comment: Only you can check why your application fails.

Comment: Your deployment failed because codedeploy was unable to stop your application, maybe investigate the logs for the error code.

Comment: Check whether the EC2 is installed Code-Deploy-Agent

Comment: In EC2 Code-Deploy-Agent is Installed

Answer (score 1):

Have you attached IAM role to the EC2 instance? If not follow:

Go to IAM console -> Roles -> Create new role
Select AWS Service -> EC2 -> Next: Permissions(don't change anything just click next) -> Next: Tags -> Next: Review -> Give a name and click Create role.

Restart the agent in EC2 using

```
sudo service codedeploy-agent restart
```

and retry deployment